# Is it possible to have a generic method with constraint of constructor with parameter?

Tags: c#

I have all kind of classes that represents entities, for example:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
    public bool IsSystemManager { get; set; }
    public bool IsSystemAdmin { get; set; }

    public Person() { }

    public Person(DataRow row)
    {
        PersonID = (int)row["person_id"];
        PersonName = row["person_name"] as string;
        IsSystemManager = (bool)row["is_manager"];
        IsSystemAdmin = (bool)row["is_admin"];
    }
}
```

And I want to have an extension to `DataTable` that turns it into a list of a class object, like this:

```
public static List<T> ToObjectList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : new(DataRow dr) //this is a compilation error
{
    List<T> lst = new List<T>();

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        lst.Add(new T(row));

    return lst;
}
```

But I can't have the constraint for contstructor with `DataRow` as a parameter.

Is there any way to have an extension method like this?

Comment: @haim770 he's returning a `List<T>` not a `List<DataRow>` and T is suppossed to take a DAtaRow in the constructor

Comment: the problem set aside, i would highly recommend not passing a datarow to the ctor but exploding the required parameters (having one for every member the ctor sets) you could pass a datarow which makes the ctor call fail easily

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't require a constructor with parameters. About the best you can do here would be to require a lambda:

```
public static List<T> ToObjectList<T>(this DataTable table,Func<DataRow,T> convert)
{
    List<T> lst = new List<T>();

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        lst.Add(convert(row));

    return lst;
}
```

Usage:

```
var list = myDataTable.ToObjectList(dr=>new Person(dr));
```

---

Further reading:

[Constraints on type parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Comment: Very nice, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify type of ***new*** constraint for generic types. What you can do however is to create two different constraints as follows:

```
public static List<T> ToObjectList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : DataRow where T : new()
```

Here you specify that your parameter T *must be of type DataTable* (or derived from DataTable) and that *new instance of it l be created inside your method*

Comment: as far as i am understanding, he does not want to return `List<DataRow>` but `List<Person>`.

Comment: TS wanted to added a constraint that DataRow must be accepted as constructor parameter  new (Datarow) and i just pointed that this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you can only require an *empty* constructor with generic constraints.

An alternative pattern would be to require a `Load` method:

```
public interface ILoadable
{
    void Load(DataRow row);
}

public class Person : ILoadable
{
    ...

    public Person() { }

    public void Load(DataRow row)
    {
        PersonID = (int)row["person_id"];
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you can declare your method as follows:

```
public static List<T> ToObjectList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : ILoadable, new()
```